# recurrence relation on a Merge Sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, mergesort, recurrence

The question is :

UNBALANCED MERGE SORT
is a sorting algorithm, which is a modified version of
the standard MERGE SORT
algorithm. The only difference is that instead of dividing
the input into 2 equal parts in each stage, we divide it into two unequal parts – the first
2/5 of the input, and the other 3/5.

a. Write the recurrence relation for the worst case time complexity of the
UNBALANCED MERGE SORT
algorithm.

b. What is the worst case time complexity of the UNBALANCEDMERGESORT
algorithm? Solve the recurrence relation from the previous section.

So i'm thinkin the recurrence relation is : T(n) <= T(2n/5) + T(3n/5) + dn.
Not sure how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: How did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: T(2n/5) and T(3n/5) is from the conquer stage and then merge it with O(n) to the d is the constant. Not really sure how to use the Master theorem here.

Comment: The [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) cannot be applied directly, however I would guess that the complexity is `O(n log n)` as for the usual Mergesort formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to look at it as "runs", where the `i`th "run" is ALL the recursive steps with depth exactly `i`.

In each such run, at most `n` elements are being processed (we will prove it soon), so the total complexity is bounded by `O(n*MAX_DEPTH)`, now, `MAX_DEPTH` is logarithmic, as in each step the bigger array is size `3n/5`, so at step `i`, the biggest array is of size `3^i/5^i * n`.

Sovle the equation:

```
3^i/5^i * n = 1
```

and you will find out that `i = log_a(n)` - for some base `a`

So, let's be more formal:

**Claim:**

> Each element is being processed by at most one recursive call at depth
>   `i`, for all values of `i`.

**Proof:**

By induction, at depth 0, all elements are processed exactly once by the first call.

Let there be some element `x`, and let's have a look on it at step i+1. We know (induction hypothesis) that `x` was processed at most once in depth `i`, by some recursive call. This call later invoked (or not, we claim at most once) the recursive call of depth `i+1`, and sent the element `x` to left OR to right, never to both. So at depth `i+1`, the element `x` is proccessed at most once.

**Conclusion:**

Since at each depth `i` of the recursion, each element is processed at most once, and the maximal depth of the recursion is logarithmic, we get an upper bound of `O(nlogn)`.

We can similarly prove a lower bound of `Omega(nlogn)`, but that is not needed, since sorting is already an `Omega(nlogn)` problem - so we can conclude the modified algorithm is still `Theta(nlogn)`.

---

If you want to prove it with "basic arithmetics", it can also be done, by induction.

**Claim:** `T(n) = T(3n/5) + T(2n/5) + n <= 5nlog(n) + n`

 It will be similar when replacing `+n` with `+dn`, I simplified it, but follow the same idea of proof with `T(n) <= 5dnlogn + dn`

**Proof**:

Base: T(1) = 1 <= 1log(1) + 1 = 1

```
T(n) = T(3n/5) + T(2n/5) + n 
<= 5* (3n/5) log(3n/5) +3n/5 + 5*(2n/5)log(2n/5) +2n/5 + n
< 5* (3n/5) log(3n/5) + 5*(2n/5)log(3n/5) + 2n
= 5*nlog(3n/5) + 2n
= 5*nlog(n) + 5*nlog(3/5) + 2n
(**)< 5*nlog(n) - n + 2n
= 5nlog(n) + n
```

(**) is because log(3/5)~=-0.22, so `5nlog(3/5) < -n`, and `5nlog(3/5) + 2n < n`

Comment: So is this statement admissible by the Master Theorem or is its application impossible here?

Comment: @Codor I am not aware of a way to prove it using master theorem, but that does not mean there is no way.

Comment: After re-reading the first case, I believe case 1 yields a worse bound of n^4 or something similar.

Comment: @Codor I think you were using `T(n) = 2T(3n/5)`, this is NOT the complexity function of this algorithm. Yes, you can use it to get an upper bound - but it will be a very loose one.

Comment: I am puzzled a bit; I would believe that the bound of `O(n log n)` can also be proven by elementary calculation (in the sense of using explicit constants), however I fail to do so...

Comment: I believe our professor wants us to answer this by elementary calculation as you say codor. Thanks for the answer amit, toda :).

Comment: @Codor Here you go, basic operations